# nginx on top of load balancer(service)

Tags: kubernetes

From this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwBdNXt6wO4) Brendan Burns talks about having a load balancer between each app layer. This makes good sense - and when he says load balancer, he is talking about a services right?

The real question is, having a service between each layer makes sense, but what about when you have a web application. Would you still need a reverse proxy like nginx as HTTP load balancer on top of the Kubernetes services. I can see the need to direct the the url to prevent a cross domain, but not for balancing since this would be handled by the Kubernetes service, right?

Then would you have pods of nginx redirecting to other services(internal cabernets load balancer/services)?

Just saw [this](http://paulbakker.io/kubernetes/load-balancing-kubernetes/). Again any comments are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are definitely use cases for which you might want a reverse proxy in front of the Kubernetes services. Experimental support is being added for this to Kubernetes version 1.1.

You can check out the design proposal [here](https://github.com/bprashanth/kubernetes/blob/lb_proposal/docs/proposals/loadbalancing.md) and an implementation using haproxy [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/service-loadbalancer).